# Same canvas to different FlipViewItems

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-store-apps

I'm using flipviews to make different approaches from my program. However i need to have the same canvas for each different view.

Is there a way to do that?

The code i have is something like this:

```
<FlipView x:Name="_flipVw1">
   <FlipViewItem x:Name="ViewModelos">
      <Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>
   </FlipViewItem>
   <FlipViewItem x:Name="ViewModelos">
      <Canvas x:Name="canvas1"/>
   </FlipViewItem>
   <FlipViewItem x:Name="ViewModelos">
      <Canvas x:Name="canvas2"/>
   </FlipViewItem>
 </FlipView>
```

Instead of this, i want to have the same canvas for all FlipViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly your `Canvas` can only have one logical parent, You will not be able to add the same `Canvas` to multiple `FlipViewItems`.

Why do they all need to be the same `Canvas`, If they just have common layout controls or somthing you could make a `ControlTemplate`.

If you explain your end goal someone may be able to help.

One idea maybe to make a `VisualBrush` that is a `Canvas`, and apply thet `VisualBrush` to all the `FlipViewItems`, when you draw all over the `VisualBrush` `Canvas` update the UI and they should all show the same.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="MyCanvasVisual">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas />
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<FlipViewItem>
    <FlipViewItem Content="{StaticResource MyCanvasVisual}" />
    <FlipViewItem Content="{StaticResource MyCanvasVisual}" />
    <FlipViewItem Content="{StaticResource MyCanvasVisual}" />
</FlipViewItem>
```

However I'm not sure where you are drawing on the Canvas, so this approch may not work in your case

Comment: It's not about the layout controls.
I have some pointer events that i want to update in canvas. And when i draw something on a canvas, i want to draw the same on all the others.

Comment: And all the `FlipViewItems` are visible at the same time?